# Python ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode, utf

I have a python script with the line:

```
string = student['name'] + "\t" + student['issueDate'] + "\n"
```

one of the observations that passes through the script has `À` (in `student['name']`) and the code always crashes in this line with the error:

> > UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0:ordinal not in range(128)

Any easy solution? I was thinking on cleaning the string at this stage of the code.

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: Where did `student[name']` come from? It looks like it was improperly read from the start of a file with a Microsoft BOM (byte-order-mark). It may be that this file should have been opened with an encoding.

Comment: `print(repr(student['name']))` would be interesting. So would `print(sys.version)`.

Comment: make sure the line is exactly this

Comment: `print(repr(student['issueDate']))` would also be interesting. It looks to me as though you need one of `student['name']` and `student['issueDate']` to be of type `unicode`, and the other to be of type `str` to get this effect.

Comment: We can't answer this question without more information from you. I'm voting to close.